# how to Sum "case when" clause after inner join without duplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am a new member of Stackoverflow (and also I'm a new of coding sql) if i do any mistakes about my question please advise me :)

I'm trying to get `SUM` of Amount in `CASE WHEN` Clause.
Here is my table

**tableA**

```
UserID  transid  Brand  Amount  
UserA   109974   MIX    960.00  --BrandMIX=A & B   
UserB   109975   B      894.00  
UserC   109976   C      350.00  
UserC   109977   MIX    300.00  --BrandMIX=C & D
```

**tableB**

```
Row transid Brand  
1   109974  A   
2   109974  B   
3   109975  B   
4   109976  C   
5   109977  C  
6   109977  D
```

I tried inner join table a and table b on a.soid = b.soid
and when i SUM it, result was wrong due to duplication of transid in table b.
here is my coding.

```
 SELECT UserID
,CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT(b.transid )) <> 0 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT(b.transid ))
    ELSE NULL END) AS 'Frequency'
,SUM(Amount) as 'TotalAmount'
,YEAR(transdatetime) AS 'Year'
,SUM (CASE [Brand] WHEN 'AA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BrandA] 
,SUM (CASE [Brand] WHEN 'BB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BrandB] 
,SUM (CASE [Brand] WHEN 'CC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BrandC] 
,SUM (CASE [Brand] WHEN 'DD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BrandD] 
,SUM (CASE [Brand] WHEN 'ZZ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BrandZ] 
FROM tableA a
INNER tableB b ON a.transid = b.transid
WHERE  is_paid = 'N'
GROUP BY UserID, YEAR(transdatetime)
```

**Result that I got**
[image]

**Result that I want**
 [image]

I added `ROW_NUMBER()` into tableB, I want to `SUM`(Amount) `WHERE` `MIN(ROW_NUMBER)`, is it impossible?
Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your row_number i.e (row column of tableB) I have modified your query to take min(row) values. Please try this...If this does not work please post the complete tables structures.

```
SELECT UserID
,CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT(b.transid )) <> 0 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT(b.transid ))
    ELSE NULL END AS 'Frequency'
,SUM(Amount) as 'TotalAmount'
,YEAR(transdatetime) AS 'Year'
,SUM (CASE [Brand] WHEN 'AA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BrandA] 
,SUM (CASE [Brand] WHEN 'BB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BrandB] 
,SUM (CASE [Brand] WHEN 'CC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BrandC] 
,SUM (CASE [Brand] WHEN 'DD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BrandD] 
,SUM (CASE [Brand] WHEN 'ZZ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BrandZ] 
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.transid = b.transid
WHERE  is_paid = 'N' AND b.row in (select min(row) from tableB group by transid)
GROUP BY UserID, YEAR(transdatetime)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, i can get correctly result from your query :)

Comment: btw, how i can vote your answer up? i clicked vote but there's nothing changes.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you, but for you to upvote I guess your reputation should be minimum 15